# Checking if IoC registrations implement command or query interfaces, and returning the generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, system.reflection, simple-injector

I am using the SimpleInjector IoC container and trying to wire-up functionality on application start-up (the container will report what command-handlers and query-handlers it has registered, and we will register the commands and queries that were registered as generic types):

```
var suppportedCommands = new List<Type>();
var container = Bootstrapper.SimpleInjectorContainer;

foreach (var registration in container.GetCurrentRegistrations())
{
    var type = registration.ServiceType;

    var isCommandHandler = type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>));

    if (isCommandHandler )
    {
        suppportedCommands.Add(type.GetGenericArguments().First());
    }
}
```

Although the registrations are returned correctly I don't seem to be able to:

1. Check if it is type that implements `ICommandHandler<SetUserStatusToVerifiedCommand>`
2. If it is, get the generic argument so we can keep track of commands we support

As an example, when I break-point on the returned registration that has the type `SetUserStatusToVerifiedCommandHandler`, the isCommandHandler variable is always false and the type string is shown as:

```
{Name = "ICommandHandler`1" FullName = "MyApp.ICommandHandler`1[[MyApp.Application.UserStatus.SetUserStatusToVerifiedCommand, MyApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"}`
```

And my interfaces and command handlers implemented as:

```
public interface ICommand
{
}

class SetUserStatusToVerifiedCommand : ICommand
{
    string UserId;
    DateTime VerifiedOn;
}

class SetUserStatusToVerifiedCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<SetUserStatusToVerifiedCommand>
{
    public void Handle(SetUserStatusToVerifiedCommand commandToHandle)
    {
    }
}
```

**Any ideas what I am doing wrong please?**

*As a sidenote, if there is any simpler way to achieve the above with SimpleInjector advice would be appreciated.*

Comment: I would probably do it the other way around. Since your commands are marked with `ICommand`, getting all commands should be as simple as `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().GetTypes().Where(typeof(ICommand).IsAssignableFrom).Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)`.

Comment: Thanks @Steven there is the potential that we would host different command handlers in different containers, as there could be two different systems (bounded contexts) running within the same process... haven't thought through the idea fully to realise the implications with scoping, but at least initially the container would be a clear boundary as I will have one container per 'system'

Comment: In that case, what you're doing makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this statement:

```
var type = registration.ServiceType;
var isCommandHandler = type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType 
    && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```

The `Type.GetInterfaces()` method returns the list of all interfaces that a certain type implements. But the `registration.ServiceType` will be a closed-generic version of `ICommandHandler<T>`. So you are basically asking what interfaces `ICommandHandler<T>` implements. And `GetInterfaces()` will not return the interface itself if called on that interface.

So instead, you need to do this:

```
var type = registration.ServiceType;

var isCommandHandler = type.IsGenericType && 
    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```